# Using ckeditor i have stored description but in view i got the data with <p> tag how can i solve it?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

When I am storing something using ekeditor in my Laravel project, I got the data in view the data with a `<p>` tag. How can I store my data without a `<p>` tag

Result:

```
<p>good<\p>
```

Expected result:

```
good
```

Comment: Sorry if I’m saying something weird, but isn’t it `</p>` instead of `<\p>`?

Answer (score 0):

use textarea instead of CKEditor if you don't want tags to be stored.

otherwise, you can try this.

if you use {{ $data->xyz }} , it will show texts with tags. So use {!! $data->xyz !!} , it won't show tags but will convert in html codes.